# Is Windows XP Pro not a good Hyper-V guest citizen?

Tags: windows-xp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 w. the Hyper-V role, I have these guest VMs:

- 3 x Windows Server 2008 R2
- 2 x Windows Server 2003 x86
- 2 x Windows 7 x64
- 1 x Windows XP Pro x86

In general, all machines are very fast and responsive. However, the Windows XP Pro guest is very sluggish.
It can take up to 2 minutes to connect to the console/or a RD session.
Sometimes it can "go into sleep" for several minutes.
I have tried to add a 2nd CPU and more memory, but it doesn't help.
When the issue happens, it's more or less impossible to get a responsive Task Manager up to analyze which process is hogging the CPU. But I have noticed that it can be various processes; lsass.exe, crss.exe etc.

Integration Services is installed. Microsoft Security Essentials is installed, but I have tried without it, no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much memory are you allocating to it? How much memory does the server itself have? I have a Server2k8 R2 Hyper-V server with similar VMs on it, and they all perform well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems to be [specific to Intel CPUs with stepping B3 or older](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/ee8ca086-e8af-44d6-9793-b45594ba6e84). In my case, I had on of the older Intel Xeon X3210 B3 stepping CPUs.
To conclude; if you want to run Windows XP 32bit on Hyper-V with an Intel processor, make sure you have a newer stepping than B3. (You will need vTPR support)

> Operating systems prior to 2003
>   Server, which includes XP and 2000, do
>   not have lazy IRQL. When an operating
>   system without IRQL runs in Hyper-V on
>   a processor without vTPR, disk
>   performance is slow. Switching to a
>   vTPR processor makes the problem go
>   away. hughescj and I have seen this.
>   The point is that the solution is not
>   to rewrite an old operating system,
>   but to use vTPR processors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try building another XP machine to see if it's that guest or something odd in the environment.  I run in under hyper-v without issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you remotely monitor it with perfmon? That may avoid the responsiveness problems of trying to launch taskman locally.

Answer (score 0):

Has the guest always been this way?  or did it start recently? If so What canged?

Was this a P2V conversion?

Is the XP guest on different storage then the rest?  Is the storage OK?